# How can I reduce the useState("") duplication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on an '**IP address tracker**' project and everything is working fine. My question is how can I reduce that `useState()` to behave like it should or can I set it as an object?

Currently I am using that method:

```js
function App() {
  const [trakerData, setTrakerData] = useState({
    ipAddress: "",
    location: "",
    timezone: "",
    isp: "",
    latitude: "",
    longitude: "",
  });

  const url = `${BASE_URL}apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&ipAddress=${ipAddress}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      axios.get(url).then((respone) => {
        setTrakerData({
          ...trakerData,
          ipAddress: respone.data.ip,
          location: respone.data.location.region,
          timezone: respone.data.location.timezone,
          isp: respone.data.isp,
          latitude: respone.data.location.lat,
          longitude: respone.data.location.lng,
        });
      });
    };

    getData();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchSection
        ipAddress={ipAddress}
        location={location}
        timezone={timezone}
        isp={isp}
        setIpAddress={setIpAddress}
      />
      <MapSection latitude={latitude} longitude={longitude} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You may also find https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useReducer useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this also works fine, but if you want to look cleaner, you can set it as object like so :

```
const [trakerData, setTrakerData] = useState({  
   ipAddress: '',
   location: '',
   // the rest values

})
```

then you can update the state values

```
 const getData = async () => {
  axios.get(url).then((respone) => {
    setTrakerData({ 
          ...trakerData,
           ipAddress: respone.data.ip,
           // rest of the valeus
      })
  });
};
```

When you pass the props to `SearchSection` you have two options, to pass the entire state or values one by one

```
<SearchSection 
   // this options is good if you update the values inside the component
   trackerData={trackerData}
   setTrackerData={setTrackerData}
   // this option is read only
   ipAddress={trackerData.ipAddress}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it says that ipAddress is not definied and rest of the values are not definied

Comment: did you remove your previous code with states and define them the way I show you on the first code block ?

Comment: Yes, of course :D *edited the code as you said

Comment: I saw the problem.. Where you pass props to `SearchSection` you have two options, to pass the whole state as props like `trakerData={trakerData}` or you can pass it one by one like `ipAddress={trakerData.ipAddress}` -- updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that work for you, declare an object with all these properties and then use them as parameters at your update functions.

This is just a snippet to give you the idea.

```
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    ipAddress: "",
    location: "",
    timezone: "",
    isp: "",
    latitude: "",
    longitude: "",
  });


  const changeFunction = useCallback((e, property) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setOptions({...options, [property]: e.target.value})
      }, []);

            <input
        value={options.timezone}
        onChange={e => changeFunction(e, 'timezone')}
        />
```

And if you need more than these and you want to go further, you could create a loop ;)

```
let obj = {}
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  obj['location' + i] = '';
  obj['timezone' + i] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can use objects or arrays to do that.

Instead of:

```
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState("");
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState("");
```

you can use:

```
const [coordinatePoint, setCoordinatePoint] = useState({latitude: "", longitude: ""});
```

Comment: It gives me the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')                                              

`const [coordinatePoint, setCoordinatePoint] = useState({
    latitude: "",
    longitude: "",
  });

setCoordinatePoint(respone.data.location.lat);
setCoordinatePoint(respone.data.location.lng);

 <MapSection latitude={coordinatePoint} longitude={coordinatePoint} />`

Comment: You need to specify the object state: 

`<MapSection latitude={coordinatePoint.latitude} longitude={coordinatePoint.longitude} />`

Also maybe location or lat is `undefined`, put `setCoordinatePoint(respone.data?.location.lat); setCoordinatePoint(respone.data?.location.lng);` and check if is everything all right.